# Parse json which has array without filed names using jackson or Gson

Tags: java, jackson, gson

I receive json which is of the following format. How do I have the corresponding Java class so that it can be mapped correctly using Jackson or Gson.

```
"data": [
    { 
        "name": "foobar",
        "timeSeries": [
            [
                1576451246,
                55.0
            ],        
            [
                1576453491,
                82.0
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

This is the Java class I have currently:

```
public class Data {

    @Key
    public String name;

    @Key
    public TimeSeries[] timeSeries;   // How will this work? What will time series class contain
}
```

Specifically I am having trouble figuring out what will TimeSeries class look like. It seems it has to be an array of int/long and float/double. But not sure how to represent that so that jackson or gson can parse correctly

Comment: Is it about Jackson, or about GSon? Those are two different libraries, and the solution won't be the same.

Comment: The solution below by pirho did work for both in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need a wrapper class - say `Response`- that holds the JSON data you get, see comments on it, how it is 'decrypted':

```
@Getter @Setter
public class Response {

    // json object named 'data' is an array holding -say- many Data objects 
    // (better name might be 'datas' or so since it has many objects, plural)
    @Getter @Setter
    private Data[] data;

    // Data contains name and and an array of Double arrays
    @Getter @Setter
    public static class Data {
        private String name;
        private Double[][] timeSeries;      
    }   

}
```

Comment: private Double[][] timeSeries; did the trick! Thanks for your prompt help!